# How to fix "Could not create a sandbox extension for temporary file" while loading a web page using WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, swift-playground

I'm currently working on an authentication flow in Playground and loading the confirmation page using `WKWebView`. It is showing a `"Could not create a sandbox extension for temporary file"` in the debug area. I have no issues in making my code work. The problem is, it is logging a lot of `"Could not create a '...' sandbox extension"` and I am having a hard time reading my own logs. The problem is also showing even with just loading any web page. For example:

```swift
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 360, height: 600))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")! //Just for example

let request = URLRequest(url: url) 

view.load(request)
```

These are the logs

```
Could not create a sandbox extension for temporary file '...'

Could not create a 'com.apple.lsd.open' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.mobileassetd' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.iconservices' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.PowerManagement.control' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.audio.AudioComponentPrefs' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.audio.AudioComponentRegistrar' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.audio.AudioQueueServer' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.audio.toolbox.reporting.service' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.endpoint.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.routediscoverer.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.routingcontext.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.volumecontroller.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.accessibility.mediaaccessibilityd' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.mediaremoted.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.audio.AudioSession' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.MediaPlayer.RemotePlayerService' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.admin' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.asset.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.assetimagegenerator.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.audiodeviceclock.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.audioprocessingtap.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.capturesession' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.capturesource' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.compressionsession' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.cpe.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.cpeprotector.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.customurlloader.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.decompressionsession' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.figcontentkeysession.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.figcpecryptor' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.formatreader.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.player.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.remaker' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.remotequeue' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.routingsessionmanager.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.samplebufferaudiorenderer.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.samplebufferrendersynchronizer.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.sandboxserver.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.sts' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.systemcontroller.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.videoqueue' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.coremedia.visualcontext.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.airplay.apsynccontroller.xpc' sandbox extension
Could not create a 'com.apple.audio.AURemoteIOServer' sandbox extension
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?